# How to escape translated text in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

My templates have large paragraphs of text.  I'm wrapping the text with {%trans%} tags, which works fine. However, I need the translations to be escaped properly. Here's an example:

```
{% trans %}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tortor urna, vestibulum vitae lacus rhoncus, scelerisque tempus nunc. 
Aliquam urna nisl, egestas eu purus id, finibus sagittis turpis. Vestibulum ut elementum neque. Integer ultrices risus et nulla cursus elementum.
Proin ac orci at neque dapibus hendrerit eu eget urna.Nam et consequat ligula. Vivamus malesuada turpis leo,
aliquet blandit arcu ultricies sed.{% endtrans %}
```

If the translated text has non-html-safe characters, how do I get trans to automatically escape?  I don't want to put all my text into a string and use the |trans filter.

Answer (score 0):

Surround your content with `{% verbatim %}TRANS IN HERE{% endverbatim %}` tags. It basically works as `|raw` filter. [Docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html)

Comment: I don't see how that does what I need? I'm looking for the opposite of raw. I want `|escape('html')` and `|escape('js')`, not raw.